# Изменить значение ключа в файле JSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Читаю данные из json с помощью Gson. И в одном активити я хочу изменить значения ключа одного обьекта. С помощью сеттера поставляю то значение которое мне нужно и в другом активити она показывается в recyclerview превосходно. Но после перезагрузки приложения все эти данные которые я поставил исчезают. Вопрос: как сохранить все мои изменения в этом локальном json файле?

```
private Category loadJSONFromDirectory() {
    Gson gson=new Gson();
    BufferedReader bf= null;
    Category category=null;
    try {
        bf= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(json));
        category=gson.fromJson(bf,Category.class);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(bf!=null)
            try {
                bf.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return category;
}



private void setFavoriteJson(boolean action) {
    Category file = loadJSONFromDirectory();
    for (Catsub catsub : file.getCatsub()) {
        for (Subcategory subcat : catsub.getSubcategories()) {
            if (subcat.getDataAll() != null) {
                for (DataAll data : subcat.getDataAll()) {
                    if (data.getId().equals(companyId)) {
                        data.setFavorites(action);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю Ваше описание и Ваш код, то Вы десериализуете json (это просто текстовые данные) в объект `Category` (это уже Java-объект в куче) и далее работаете именно с Java-объектом, а не с прочитанными Вами текстовыми данными.

Для того, чтобы сохранить изменения, Вам нужно после внесённых изменений сериализовать объект обратно в json и сохранить в файл.

```
private void saveJsonToFile(String filePath, Category data) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
        gson.toJson(data, writer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати, Вы можете создать один объект `Gson` и использовать его везде, где это необходимо, а не создавать его каждый раз для каждой операции. [Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432758/should-i-reuse-one-instance-of-gson-or-create-new-ones-on-demand) говорят, что это даже полезно.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, да я так и сделал, и согласен с тем что это очень полезно.

Comment: сработало,но одна проблема, файл сохраняется очень долго, где лучше всего вызвать этот метод?

Comment: Может мне написать Сервис?

Comment: Да, так будет надёжнее. Смотрите даже сразу в сторону `IntentService`. К слову, обычно сериализация становится длинной при действительно больших объёмах данных. Возможно, в вашем случае будет удобнее использовать для хранения базу данных (обычно проще всего Realm).

Comment: а возможно ли изменить только одно значение в файле json, чтоб не переписать весь файл?

Comment: В общем случае нет. Разве что скопировать файл рядом, внеся нужные изменения. Если файл разбит на строки, то можно читать построчно, искать нужную строку, меня в ней что нужно и записывать в выходной файл. Если файл не разбит на строки, то можно конечно считывать джсон-токены потоковым парсером и сразу писать их в выходной файл, но имхо проще оставить как есть и  вынести в сервис. Ещё можете попробовать не десериализовывать джсон в объект, а просто распарсить в `JsonElement` и потом его же изменить и сохранить, должно работать быстрее.

Comment: Хорошо , попробую и напишу )